# WMD editor bug: German keyboard layout - "@" creates blockquote section

Tags: bug, status-completed, editor, keyboard

Looking at the WMD editor tooltips, I see that Ctrl+Q is supposed to create a blockquote:

```
"Blockquote <blockquote> Ctrl+Q"
```

In the German keyboard layout, the @ and Q share one key, you would press <kbd>ALT-GR</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> or the equivalent (as far as keycodes go) <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to get an @.

You can probably see where this leads: Every time I want to type an @ I get:

```
> Blockquote
```

on a new line. Doing many XSLT questions I need the @ quite often. Either I type all the code in an external editor, or I need to copy-paste a single @ off some other place around the browser. Every. time.

This annoys the hell out of me. I think checking the CRTL-Q shortcut for the state of the ALT key (must not be depressed) would fix this.

Comment: there's a "Gr" key?

Comment: @Jason S: on German keyboards there is a ALT-GR key where on US keyboards is the right ALT key.

Comment: Not only German keyboards, Turkish keyboards have GR too :)

Comment: Spanish keyboards also have this key.

Comment: Irish keyboards also have this key. On some symbols it gives you an alternative alternative (the € sign, the ¦ broken pipe characted). Alt-GR Q doesn't give me @ in anything however, @ is shift+' for me.

Comment: What browser are you using? This doesn't happen to me.

Comment: Firefox 3.5, on Windows XP, Keyboard layout is "German (IBM)". I'm checking with "German (Germany)"... same thing. I type "@", I get "> Blockquote"

Comment: Just restarted Firefox in Safe Mode to make sure it's not an addon's fault. Behavior is unchanged.

Comment: I get the same behaviour on Windows Vista with FF 3.5; however not on Linux with FF 3.0.

Comment: I can reproduce this in Safe Mode.

Comment: This might very well be Windows related. Which not makes it less annoying. ;-)

Comment: BTW Opera 9.5 shows `> @`.

Comment: Duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2051/why-is-alt-gr-q-giving-me-quote-formatting-instead-of-the-sign/2342#2342

Comment: The problem cause and solution can be derived from: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AltGr_key#History - As I said, checking for the ALT key would probably fix this (and all the other ALT-GR related) errors.

Comment: +1, annoying as hell :) (Chrome on XP)

Comment: This has been an enriching conversation about keyboards

Comment: So this is not by design! +1, this is horribly annoying.

Comment: And Italian keyboards too. and their @ sign is on teh H or J  or K key. Definitely not on the L key

Comment: I wish I could type `]` characters in Stack Overflow... :_(

Comment: @Jason S, it is not Gr, it is Alt Gr

Comment: I cannot type @ too. I use Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:2.0b2pre) Gecko/20100719 Minefield/4.0b2pre, and Turkish Q keyboard. I'm talking about "Alt Gr + q"

Comment: @ilhan please vote to re-open the question. It has been closed as a dupe for another question, but the other question has been closed as a dupe for *this one*! Circular dependency of two closed questions sucks. Please also ask others to vote for to re-open the question!

Comment: fixed in dev ...

Comment: @waffles: you might want to close [my similar question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51389/ctrlshift-ctrlalt-keyboard-shortcuts-in-the-wmd-editor) as a dupe and/or add `[status-planned]` too.  I never found this post (for obvious reasons), but it's clearly the same issue.  Thanks for the fix.

Comment: @waffles: Finally. Great to hear a fix is underway!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CTRL-ALT combination no longer maps to any shortcuts CTRL-Q and the rest of them.

Sorry it took us so long to sort this.

Comment: Ohhhh it's so nice when the pain goes away… Thank you! \*frolicks\* :-)

Comment: Now, while you are at it: Can you do the same for CTRL-SHIFT? (CTRL-SHIFT-I should not invoke the "italics" shortcut, only CTRL-I should.) Thanks! :-)

Comment: @Tomalak can you open a separate issue on that so we can track it ?

Comment: Done - [WMD editor bug: CTRL-* and CTRL-SHIFT-* shortcuts collide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58076/)

Comment: there already was a separate issue open for it, but you marked it as status-completed: [Ctrl+Shift, Ctrl+Alt keyboard shortcuts in the WMD editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51389/ctrlshift-ctrlalt-keyboard-shortcuts-in-the-wmd-editor)

Answer (score 13):

Background: why [Ctrl-Alt should never be used for keyboard shortcuts](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040329-00/?p=40003). There are *many* other potentially-troublesome characters... indeed, on the keyboard I use, almost every AltGr+letter combination is used for typing various symbols.

If WMD must use the Ctrl key for shortcuts (and it's questionable, in a browser), it should check that the Alt key is not also held down before triggering.

Answer (score 5):

A similar issue is <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> (next to 0 in the upper row) on this Finnish/Swedish keyboard layout that normally would output a backslash but now toggles backtick `enter code here`.

So far when having to enter a backslash, I've typed it in some other app and then copy-pasted to SO answer box.

Comment: Oh, didn't realise I could have left a comment with 1 rep on mSO, unlike SO where you need 50.

Comment: add French keyboard (use AltGr+**+** for the **}** symbol)

Answer (score 5):

Yes. How can you treat so badly your users from a country that invented a waffle variation as beautiful as this? (Yes, apparently we came up with the [heart-shaped waffle](http://www.bergisches-wiki.de/index.php/Bergische_Waffeln).)

[alt text http://media.kuechengoetter.de/media/105/12216445942780/waffeln_zutat.jpg](http://media.kuechengoetter.de/media/105/12216445942780/waffeln_zutat.jpg)

Comment: Ein Hoch auf herzförmige Waffeln! Rechtecke sind hässlich.

Comment: Germanen est un weirdesch-lookinen languageschmord.

Comment: [Can I ask question in English and let know users they can answer in Spanish?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44080/can-i-ask-question-in-english-and-let-know-users-they-can-answer-in-spanish)

Comment: @Downvoter: That's about Spanish. Totally unrelated.

Comment: @bal, It's about using different languageschmords

Comment: @Juan Manuel: I'll translate it for you: "Cheers to heart shaped waffles! Rectangles are ugly."

Answer (score 3):

This is how the WMD Editor works. Since Shift + 2 is @ in american keyboards and does not cause trouble there.

This question could be turned into [this UV item](http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/pages/1722-general/suggestions/230521-fix-key-binding-for-ctrl-q-in-wmd-editor) if the mods change it.

Comment: The URL is dead, and the whole uservoice thing predates my time here; is there a new URL for this?

Answer (score 2):

These are just shortcuts in the editor. "AltGr" is equal to Ctrl + Alt on a US keyboard. So the shortcuts in question are ctrl+alt+q and ctrl+alt+1.

Comment: ALT-GR is equivalent to CRTL+ALT, not to CTRL+SHIFT. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AltGr_key#History

Answer (score 2):

I see the same behavior. Of course, you can work around this by typing `Left Alt` + NumPad `0` `6` `4`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the shortcuts in the WMD editor will have to get localized to solve this...

Comment: In general, localized keyboard shortcuts are terrible. You need to learn a different set of shortcuts for each language you understand and you need to stop and think about the lang of the software every time you use them. Does SO need so many keyboard shortcuts that you absolutely have to use Ctrl+Alt?