# Problem with the closing brace

Tags: bug, status-completed, keyboard

When I ask a question or post an answer in SO, if I want to write the } character, it behaves as if I click on the "Code sample" button (the one with *101010*)...

In others words, when I click on the } key *, I get this:

```
enter code here
```

or (if I type } in a paragrah):

```
`enter code here`
```

Is there any reason that I get this behavior?

How to solve this issue (except by writing a } outside the text area and copy/paste it)?

* important note: I have an AZERTY keyboard, configured for the french langage...

Comment: What browser are you using? I've never seen that. It sounds like } may be being confused with Ctrl-K...

Comment: I'm using Firefox 3.5.2, and I am not aware of such a mapping...

Comment: The } character is on the key used also for '+' and '=', left to the backspace key. If I press this key with AltGr or Ctrl, I get this behavior...

Comment: I just made the test with IE6 (sorry), and the closing brace is displayed correctly. So maybe this is due to a Firefox plugin?

Comment: same here, firefox 3.5.5, french azerty keyboard

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Found [the bug](http://github.com/derobins/wmd/blob/master/wmd.js#L1112)!

### Explanation

Actually, WMD listens to the `keydown` event which contains a `keyCode` and no `charCode` (only `keypress` actually contains a `charCode`) but considers `keyCode` and `charCode` to be the same thing.

This is wrong!

Actually, `keyCode` and `charCode` may give you the same letter, but that is not true for every letter.

For example:

```
String.fromCharCode(107) == 'k' // 107 is the charCode for "k"
String.fromCharCode(75) == 'K' // 75 is the keyCode for key K
```

Wow, the fact that the `keyCode` of K is the same as the `charCode` of "K" charCode is only a coincidence (or maybe history). But this is not true for every keys!

For example:

```
String.fromCharCode(107) == 'k' // 107 is the keyCode for key =
String.fromCharCode(61) == '=' // 61 is the charCode for "="
```

So when typing <kbd>k</kbd>, WMD sees no `charCode` (since it handles `keydown`) and uses the `keyCode` 75 instead which gives `K`. That's why <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> is working as expected.

But when typing <kbd>=</kbd>, WMD still sees no `charCode`and used the `keyCode` 107 which gives `k`. Boom, WMD thinks we typed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> while we actually typed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> (this is how you type a `}` on azerty french keyboard).

### How to fix it

Actually, it's not that easy.

Relying on the `keydown` event means that there is no easy way to know what character has been typed, only what key has been typed.

But we can still rely on the `keyCode` being 75 to trigger our shortcut. This means that it may not be the same letter for everyone.

Comment: excellent, we plan to look at this in the next few weeks. thank you.

Comment: I used <kbd> to markup actual keys instead of characters but the rendering is not as nice as in SO.

Comment: It was "fixed" to prevent abuse. @vin

Answer (score 2):

}

Works for me! Perhaps your } key is aliased to Ctrl-K, which is the code block shortcut in the editor?

Answer (score 1):

I also have the same issue with various versions of firefox v3+, and a French AZERTY keyboard as well.
Sometimes I can insert plain closing braces, but not always.
The plugins I systematically use are:

- adblock plus
- all in one gesture
- firebug
- webdevelopper
- tab mix plus

The bug is not systematic, but very common. I can't tell what changes the times I don't observe it.

It seems to be the same issue as [this one about AltGr+Q on German keyboards](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13065/wmd-editor-bug-german-keyboard-layout-creates-blockquote-section), and this one [on Finish keyboards](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2051/why-is-alt-gr-q-giving-me-quote-formatting-instead-of-the-sign/2342#2342)

Answer (score 0):

One way you should be able to include the enclosing brace while this is being fixed - type it in another application, such as Notepad, and then copy/paste it into the input text box.

Comment: We are quite aware of this workaround. Firefox plugins like *It's all Text* are even better workarounds.