# Formatting code in Stack Overflow and French keyboard

Tags: support, keyboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problem with the closing brace](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19330/problem-with-the-closing-brace)

HI use a French keyboard, and I am having difficulties writing a <kbd>**`}`**</kbd> symbol in the edit window.

When I type **Alt**<kbd>+</kbd>**+** (the French keyboard shortcut for this symbol), the backtick escape

```
`enter code here`
```

appears... I am forced to write this symbol elsewhere and then paste it into the textbox.

Comment: @Serhio: meta.stackoverflow.com is the place to discuss questions about stack overflow itself.  The question will probably be auto migrated over there shortly.

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2051/why-is-alt-gr-q-giving-me-quote-formatting-instead-of-the-sign/2342#2342

Comment: @bobince yaah... i see the similar questions, but no really workaround or "bug fix" promesse :)

Answer (score 1):

Same problem with German Layout and the @ character:

[WMD editor bug: German keyboard layout - "@" creates blockquote section](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13065/wmd-editor-bug-german-keyboard-layout-creates-blockquote-section)

Comment: but there is no answer...

Comment: @serhio: Now, there is. Apparently a fix is in the works.