# How do I escape backslashes in markdown?

Tags: discussion, markdown

How do I type "backslash backslash servername" on a **European keyboard**, like this \\ServerName, (without just pasting a backslash from the clipboard).

Typing backslash just seems to toggle the code block on and off.

EDIT: This an issue for keyboard layouts where backslash is activated by a combination of AltGr + backslash.

Comment: "European keyboard"? What's one of those? Is my UK keyboard not European? I have no difficulty with backslashes. I assume you mean Swedish keyboard.

Comment: If you're a programmer and can't easily type a backslash, you have bigger problems than markdown...

Comment: this was from serverfault, but I think it's a reasonable concern -- outside of HTML <tags> most stuff renders as you type it, except \\

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13065/wmd-editor-bug-german-keyboard-layout-creates-blockquote-section
(different problem, perhaps a common solution)

Answer (score 7):

Just use four backslashes: \\\\Server -> \\Server

Comment: I had trouble with putting backslash in inline code block: ``\``. Solution I found is to use `\`\`\\`\``.

Answer (score 2):

Type the HTML entity `"&#92;"` for each backslash, **outside** of a backtick-demarcated area, like so \\ServerName\share.

Answer (score 2):

You can type out the decimal value of any character on the number pad.
Backslash is Alt+0092

Comment: Doesn't that only work in MS Word?

Comment: \\ ... @Æther: nope, seems to work just fine in Firefox on WinXP

Answer (score 1):

\\ServerName (by which I mean `\\\\ServerName`) seems to work for me...

Comment: I'm using a European keyboard, and the backslash is a combination AltGr + backslash, which just activates the code block in the ServerFault edit box.

Comment: You can't type a backslash without AltGr? hmm... you could, in principle, use an alternate keyboard layout, but using an HTML entity or the numeric keypad (if you're on Windows) is probably easier.

Answer (score 1):

\\servername - typed with no problem on a international keyboard set for swedish layout using altgr, using Chrome though...