# Escape backslash inside string for syntax highlighting

Tags: bug, syntax-highlighting

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9910716/2071807) has a block of code containing a string like `"\foo\"`.

The syntax highlighting (reasonably enough) assumes the `\"` is an escaped double-quote and continues the highlighting for string for the remainder of the code block.

I've tried [multiple backslashes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34383/how-do-i-escape-backslashes-in-markdown), and this prevents the second slash from escaping the quote, but also shows both slashes!

How can this be improved upon?

```vba
dim someVar as Variant

someVar = "\foo\" & thisShouldNotBeStringHighlighted
"
someVar = "\foo\\" & tooManySlashes
```

Comment: Ah, I've just seen [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/253241) about Google Prettify and how it's not StackExchange's tool.