# Can I ask question in English and let know users they can answer in Spanish?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

Can I ask question in English and let know users they can answer in Spanish?

this question was born cuz of this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520065/donde-puedo-encontrar-guias-de-programacion-para-c-en-espanol

Puedo poner preguntas y decirle a los usuarios que pueden contestar en español?
esta pregunta nacio por esto:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520065/donde-puedo-encontrar-guias-de-programacion-para-c-en-espanol

nota: pueden contestar en español!!!

Comment: dupe (sort of): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/is-english-required-on-stackoverflow

Comment: @Michael Todd: just (sort of)

Comment: Please clarify: Is this that they *can* answer in Spanish or that they *should*?

Comment: the title says it - `can`

Answer (score 11):

No.

English is the *lingua franca* of Stack Overflow (some would dare say programming). If you tell someone they can answer in Spanish just to solve your problem, that leaves everyone else who uses this site that *doesn't* speak Spanish out in the cold.

That would be akin to going into a Chinese web forum and asking them to post their answer in English. I can imagine that would go over Really Well™.

Comment: There seem to have been efforts to create a Spanish SO-clone. However, the project was not successful: http://mig.cl/2010/01/25/no-mas-codigo-de-maquina/

Comment: and keeping this site in english deprives all spanish users...

Comment: @luiscencio : "Deprives"? What does it take away from you that is yours? Nothing. If there is a market for a spanish speaking programming Q & A site, why not fill the need?

Comment: @Luiscencio,  If you believe there is a market for it, the engine is already available http://www.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I love the irony of using a non-english phrase in this answer +un

Comment: @heavyd stackexchange doesn't support internationalization: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4169/any-progress-in-se-localization there's only a JQuery based workaround.

Answer (score 6):

There's a (fresh new) Spanish programming forum which uses Stackexchange engine: http://comunidad.desarrolloopensource.com (alias link http://devopensource.stackexchange.com )

Comment: cheers for the "not here, sorry, but try there" approach!

Comment: I am however not sure if it suits his needs (pretty little and not active forum). But that's the only which I can Google up as far. Hole in market indeed.

Comment: it is "web development and design" only

Comment: I'm sorry for that. Well, you can consider to start up one. Spanish is the second (latin) language after English. There must surely be a market. The only other Spanish stackexchange-based forum I can find is http://www.mesadeayuda.org but this is for hardware and software only.

Answer (score 5):

See

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/

Answer (score 5):

La razón por la cual no se permiten preguntas/respuestas en otros idiomas es para evitar fragmentación del conocimiento.

Es beneficioso para los no-nativos al inglés aprender el idioma puesto que la gran mayoría del conocimiento existente se encuentra en inglés. Además también aparece antes en ese idioma.

Para buscar información en español, lamentablemente tendrás que ir a otro lado, pero será realmente una gran ventaja para vos aprender y desarrollar tu inglés, principalmente desde el punto de vista profesional.

Yo uso principalmente Stack Overflow u otras webs en inglés, pero he escuchado buenas cosas sobre www.elguille.info.

Dicho eso, siempre y cuando preguntes en inglés (que la comunidad sajona pueda entenderte), [podés agregar lo que quieras](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/is-english-required-on-stackoverflow/13679#13679).

---

*The reason questions/answers in other languages are not alowed is to avoid knowledge fragmentation.*

*It's beneficial for non-speakers to learn English as most of the existing knowledge it's written in that language, and also appears first in it.*

*To search for information in Spanish, sadly you'll have to go somewhere else, but it will be a great advantage for you to learn and develop your English, mainly from a professional point of view.*

*I mainly use Stack Overflow or other webpages in English, but I've heard good things about www.elguille.info.*

*That being said, as long as you have an English version for them to understand you, you can add whatever you want.*

Answer (score 4):

Work on the [Spanish Stack Overflow site will begin in August of 2015](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12731/any-update-about-this-site).  The site will be launched late October - early November of 2015.  Once the site is launched, users who have questions in Spanish can ask and get expert answers to their questions in Spanish.

I hope to see you there!