# Turn Minus Vote To Positive

Tags: discussion

Can I have a right to turn my question's **minus points to positive**?. As because of the **peers'** misunderstanding the question voted to minus but as far my point of  view it's useful for knowledge. if such type of circumstance occurred between two of those who is wright?. who will going to decide it?. I have notice in my case most of the minus points is due to language barrier and misunderstanding. It's happen and will happen because of we are dealing globally and very large basis. If we are dealing globally than we must have to face **language barrier** as there is in the world variety of languages and culture. We should have to give the importance to the question not languages. Not languages means there should be **English** but we have to compromise with it and modified it in English as we are doing this by the way of modify other question. It's our good practice. So if some user like me believe that his question is important for knowledge than who is the **mediator** to decide who is right?. Obviously the who give minus points is believe that he is right and i believe my question is important for knowledge hence i believe that i am right. if i believe so,  than can i have a right to turn my minus vote  to positive?.

Comment: Perhaps you could link to some of the material you feel has been misjudged?

Comment: @dmckee, my question got minus points on so title not exactly but nearest about :- Copy Winform for showing as demo. which is deleted by me.

Comment: OK. Found [it (10k only link)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3899098/). That particular question seems to be about asking questions in a "forum". Now, perhaps you meant Stack Overflow which is decidedly *not* a forum in the usual internet sense, but either way the question isn't really on topic.

Comment: Mahesh, you make a lot of fuss about 1 downvote. You may want to grow a slightly thicker skin for participating on these sites. And internet in general.

Comment: (As an aside, just to be sure you know: voting patterns here on Meta [are](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270/the-meaning-of-down-votes-in-meta-vs-stackoverflow) [different](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15251/meta-faq-page-should-include-more-verbiage-about-downvotes) from the patterns on the actual sites.)

Comment: What's up with the random "bolded" words?

Answer (score 14):

> Can I have a right to turn my
>   question's minus points to positive?.

If you're asking if you can turn some of the downvotes into upvotes, then no.

> As because of the peers'
>   misunderstanding he would voted to
>   minus but as far my point of view it's
>   useful for knowledge and between two
>   of those who is wright?. who will
>   going to decide it?.

The community.

> I have notice in my case most of the
>   minus points is due to language
>   barrier and misunderstanding. It's
>   happen and will happen because of we
>   are dealing globally and very large
>   basis. If we are dealing globally than
>   we must have to face language barrier
>   as there is in the world variety of
>   languages and culture.

And I agree. English is of course not read/written/spoken by everybody. [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56061/is-atrocious-english-a-possible-sign-of-rudeness) [has](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44080/can-i-ask-question-in-english-and-let-know-users-they-can-answer-in-spanish) [been](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5747/an-alternative-to-translation-for-non-english-speakers) [discussed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16276/editing-for-broken-english-acceptable) [on](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31309/i-think-we-need-a-flag-for-non-english-speakers) [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/is-english-required-on-stack-overflow) [many](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8162/we-need-to-help-non-english-speakers-somehow) [times](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15308/whats-the-best-way-to-ask-a-question-if-english-isnt-your-first-language).

> We should have to give the importance
>   to the question not languages.

And I agree to this as well. Votes should be based on how well the question was asked, and not on what language it's written in. In a majority of cases, this is true.

> Not languages means there should be
>   English but we have to compromise with
>   it and modified it in English as we
>   are doing this by the way of modify
>   other question. It's our good
>   practice.

This is in fact encouraged. Users with edit capabilities should be editing posts to improve them.

> So if some user like me believe that
>   his question is important for
>   knowledge than who is the mediator to
>   decide who is right?.

The community.

> Obviously the who give minus points is
>   believe that he is right and i believe
>   my question is important for knowledge
>   hence i believe that i am right.

I don't agree with this statement. A majority of cases downvotes are a reflection on how badly the question was asked, in my experience,

> if i believe so, than can i have a
>   right to turn my minus vote to
>   positive?.

Again, no.

> If we are dealing globally than we
>   must have to face language barrier as
>   there is in the world variety of
>   languages and culture.

Again, I agree. English is of course not read/written/spoken by everybody. [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56061/is-atrocious-english-a-possible-sign-of-rudeness) [has](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44080/can-i-ask-question-in-english-and-let-know-users-they-can-answer-in-spanish) [been](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5747/an-alternative-to-translation-for-non-english-speakers) [discussed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16276/editing-for-broken-english-acceptable) [on](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31309/i-think-we-need-a-flag-for-non-english-speakers) [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/is-english-required-on-stack-overflow) [many](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8162/we-need-to-help-non-english-speakers-somehow) [times](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15308/whats-the-best-way-to-ask-a-question-if-english-isnt-your-first-language).

> So if some user like me believe that
>   his question is important for
>   knowledge than who is the mediator to
>   decide who is right?

Again, the community.

Comment: @silico, tell me how much time you voted down? it's important please reply.

Comment: @mahesh: Why is such information important? As long as people ask non-bad questions/create non-bad answers, I won't downvote.

Comment: @Silico, that's it what i am trying to tell you. See you are not agree with my points of people/peers who give minus points they are believe that they are right ok. this is only first part. what about question asker  is he not right to show or explain his way?

Comment: @Silico, Is this bad comment which i asked for answer? or you are not trying to understand my question here in third comment?.

Comment: @mahesh: I really don't understand what's the issue here. If you are downvoted, it usually means that some members of the community has identified your question as poorly asked. In that case, you should edit your question to try to clarify/improve it, using feedback from the community as a guide if there's any. Don't take downvotes personally - a majority of downvotes are not a reflection on you as a user, but rather a reflection on the quality/helpfulness of the post as determined by the community.

Comment: And, @mahesh, *patience* helps a lot too. Comments are not a chatbox, and are not personal either; relax, no need to ask for replies within 10 minutes after posting some comment. Enjoy!

Comment: @Arjan, You are very right i am totally agree with you,but what are you doing when you comment on some one instead of receiving answer you received down vote one by one.

Answer (score 7):

If several of your peers are misunderstanding your question, that's likely to be because the question is poorly written. It is your responsibility as the questioner to ask questions as clearly as possible - if it's hard to tell what is being asked, or you've left out very important details, why on earth should you expect to get upvotes?

I understand that it can be difficult if English isn't your first language, but it's still possible to get your point across a lot better than you did in [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899098). In particular:

- It was unclear exactly what you wanted
- It was unclear how it related to programming (rather than just "how to post a screenshot into a forum")
- It was unclear what you'd tried

I don't see why you'd expect a downvote to be turned into an upvote. If a downvote is undeserved, you'll usually get upvotes as well. Trust the community. If it's a genuinely poor question (which it is in this case, I believe) then you should expect downvotes, and I don't see any problem in that.

Comment: @Jon, suppose you are writing an article on programing and there is lots control utilized on form and you are not able to describe it in words or phrase so what are you doing? How can you show the demo to the people to turn your way. Note:- most of the programing article shows demo of forms with supporting other controls so it is very much related to programing. If some people don't know how to ask question properly and there is need of demo so there is also require the screenshots demo.

Comment: @mahesh: The question was only *tangentially* related to programming, in that you *happen* to want to show a form. However, you're really asking two general questions of "how do I show a picture on a forum" and "how do I take a screenshot", neither of which are programming-specific. In particular, you didn't ask how to do any of this *programmatically*, which is what would make it relevant to Stack Overflow.

Comment: @jon, I am very much believe in community but my question related to not understand my question due to language barrier and ultimately it down voted. I am lots trying to tell our community that not give importance to language give important to question. of course question should ask in English is important here.

Comment: @mahesh: I don't believe your question *was* downvoted because of the language. I suspect it was downvoted for the reasons explained in the bullet points in my answer. You could have made your question a lot clearer despite your difficulties with English. *It was a poor question.* The sooner you accept that and try harder with future questions, the more you'll get out of Stack Overflow. Blaming others because you asked an unclear and off-topic question isn't going to help you.

Comment: @Jon, Ok Now I understand your point. can I ask now. How to do it by programmatically?.

Comment: @mahesh, *can I ask now. How to do it by programmatically?* No! This is NOT the place to ask that. The communities are supposed to be a huge archive of questions and answers, searchable by others too. Trying to get your answer this way, is only helping you, not the community! Instead, please edit your question on Stack Overflow and vote to undelete it.

Comment: @Arjan, it's already deleted on SO by me.

Comment: @mahesh, you can click the undelete link, after you clarified [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3899098/). Jon, sorry for spamming you with all these comment notifications ;-)

Comment: @Arjan, I am trying on Google Search and SO Search but fail to find question. I don't know how to do it?.

Comment: @mahesh, so [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899098/how-to-copy-winform-for-showing-demo) (which dmckee and I already linked earlier) is not the one? Then see Jeff's answer in [How do I find questions or answers that I've deleted?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13193/how-do-i-find-questions-or-answers-that-ive-deleted/63313#63313) (And please consider *not* deleting things just because of downvotes. Especially not if somebody tried to help and already answered. Instead, please improve the post.)

Comment: @Arjan Sub-10k users can only undelete their answers easily. They can only undelete their questions if they never navigated away from the page, because once it is deleted they'll get the standard "Page cannot be found" upon visiting it later.