# Keyboard shortcut bug with Italian layout

Tags: bug, status-completed, keyboard-shortcuts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is Alt Gr + Q giving me Quote formatting instead of the @ sign?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13065/wmd-editor-bug-german-keyboard-layout-creates-blockquote-section)

Hi, when using the Italian keyboard layout, I can't insert the ] symbol (closing square brace) because when I press `AltGr + è` the editor inserts an inline code block, despite its shortcut is said to be `Ctrl + k` by the tooltip.

Here you can find an Italian keyboard: http://img704.imageshack.us/img704/5640/keyboardwz.jpg

Comment: You've circled the wrong key. You mention "]", but you've circled "[". Anyway, how did you enter it when asking this question?

Comment: Dupe http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2051/why-is-alt-gr-q-giving-me-quote-formatting-instead-of-the-sign/ it's another key, but the solution is the same: Check for `Alt` key to avoid `Alt Gr` combinations.

Comment: @ChrisF: One way is to copy from another source and paste it in, otherwise keep the left Alt pressed and digit 93 on the number pad with NumLock on.

Comment: fair enough.