# StackOverflow Code Sample vs }

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, keyboard-shortcuts

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Is there a way to disable the hotkeys?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2980/is-there-a-way-to-disable-the-hotkeys)
>   [Why is Alt Gr + Q giving me Quote formatting instead of the @ sign?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2051/why-is-alt-gr-q-giving-me-quote-formatting-instead-of-the-sign)
>   [Option to disable keyboard shortcuts in WMD](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3245/option-to-disable-keyboard-shortcuts-in-wmd)

I want to ask you a question about the stackoverflow's editor.

Whenever I need to write code and close a } I get the Code Sample indentation if using:

```
Alt gr + Shift + (+*])
```

It's pretty annoying, is there any way to avoid this other than:

```
Ctrl+v
```

?

Thank you and sorry if this has been asked before.

EDIT:

Sorry never knew about meta.

Comment: This is a http://meta.stackoverflow.com question.

Comment: Will go to meta --> follow up over there...

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2980/is-there-a-way-to-disable-the-hotkeys http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47316/please-do-not-hijack-command-q http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3245/option-to-disable-keyboard-shortcuts-in-wmd http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44414/keyboard-shortcut-bug-with-italian-layout