# Ctrl+Shift, Ctrl+Alt keyboard shortcuts in the WMD editor

Tags: bug, status-completed, editor, keyboard-shortcuts

Sometimes when I'm answering a Javascript question, I'll open Chrome's console so that I can just check something quickly before I finish my post.  The keyboard shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>.  The problem is that WMD mistakes this shortcut as the `<em>`/italic shortcut.  The same problem exists in Opera, and Safari (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>).

To clarify, this could potentially be a blocking issue in all browsers, and does not specifically apply to this keyboard combination, but all WMD Ctrl-key combinations.

Can [`!event.shiftKey && !event.altKey`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Events-20001113/events.html#Events-MouseEvent-altKey) be added so that keyboard shortcuts operate on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> only?

Answer (score 3):

Ok we are checking for CTRL-ALT now and not mapping any shortcuts to that pair.