# WMD editor bug: CTRL-* and CTRL-SHIFT-* shortcuts collide

Tags: bug, editor, keyboard-shortcuts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ctrl+Shift, Ctrl+Alt keyboard shortcuts in the WMD editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51389/ctrlshift-ctrlalt-keyboard-shortcuts-in-the-wmd-editor)

Closely related to [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13065/) (*<kbd>CTRL-[Letter]</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL-ALT-[Letter]</kbd> collide*), there is another small glitch to fix in the WMD editor:

The keyboard shortcuts of the WMD editor work like <kbd>CTRL-[Letter]</kbd>. However, the state of the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key is not checked, so that <kbd>CTRL-SHIFT-[Letter]</kbd> invokes the WMD editor shortcut as well.

This leads to collisions, for example in Google Chrome:

- <kbd>CTRL-I</kbd> – WMD shortuct for "*Italics*"
- <kbd>CTRL-SHIFT-I</kbd> – Google Chrome shortcut for "Developer Tools"

Consequently, invoking the Chrome developer tools from within the WMD editor area is not possible.

Other browser- or OS-specific key combinations might be affected as well. To avoid such collisions, editor keyboard shortcuts should work only when pressed exactly as advertised.

---

*This question was opened as requested by @waffles♦ over [in the other thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13065/wmd-editor-bug-german-keyboard-layout-creates-blockquote-section/57980#57980).*

Comment: This is actually a dupe, I mentioned Ctrl+Shift combination in my question, citing Google Chrome Developer Tools as the issue there too - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51389/ctrlshift-ctrlalt-keyboard-shortcuts-in-the-wmd-editor