# WMD shortcut conflict with Unicode input mode (CTRL + SHIFT + U)

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, editor, keyboard-shortcuts

The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>U</kbd> WMD shortcut turns the current line in a list item.
The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>U</kbd> shortcut triggers the [unicode input mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_input#In_X11).

[Ctrl+Shift, Ctrl+Alt keyboard shortcuts in the WMD editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/51389/169101?ctrlshift-ctrlalt-keyboard-shortcuts-in-the-wmd-editor) is tagged [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed). However, the Ctrl+Shift combinations haven't been fixed yet.

Can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> (or at least +<kbd>U</kbd>) be remapped to nothing? It's not nice to manually delete the generated lists after using the Unicode input mode.

Comment: I for one would love to have a way to turn off all the WMD shortcuts completely. Let my browser's controls do all the work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, only the Alt key was special-cased back then. I've added the Shift key.