# You can vote to close two questions as duplicates of each other

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prevent circular close as exact duplicate loop](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54024/prevent-circular-close-as-exact-duplicate-loop)

As I demonstrated with these two questions:

- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61559/can-a-question-be-a-duplicate-of-a-duplicate-of-itself
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61562/can-a-question-be-a-duplicate-of-a-duplicate-of-itself

You can vote to close two questions as duplicates of each other.

Comment: I *know* this has to be a dupe.

Comment: Does this ever actually happen though? I don't think I've seen a real case of this on SO before

Comment: Oh, the dup post has an example where it actually happened

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be a bit strange if vote-to-close was disallowed. Consider e.g. voting to close `A` as a duplicate of `B`, then being subsequently convinced that `B` is the better master question. Now you can't give the (possibly final) close vote on `B` as we can't take back close-votes.

There should however be a check in place when the actual closing happens to prevent circles.