# How should I develop a minimal example of an SO bug for an MSO bug report?

Tags: support, bug-reports

There is an [MSO sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox).  However, <s>it requires 10 reputation on MSO</s>, which unsurprisingly, I don't yet have while reporting my first SO bug on MSO.  I could find no SO sandbox.  So, how should I develop a minimal example of an SO bug for an MSO bug report?

UPDATE: the "10 rep to use the MSO sandbox" restriction has been removed in response to this question.  However, it turns out [the bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130736/bug-in-your-post-appears-to-contain-code-that-is-not-properly-formatted-as-code#comment359344_130736) I was reproducing is specific to SO, since the [MSO sandbox accepts it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130744/184610).  So, I need a solution that lets me test against the SO submission-rejection heuristics directly.

My approach was to create a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376438/im-trying-to-create-a-minimal-example-of-a-stackoverflow-bug-i-was-asked-to-rep#comment13376171_10376438) on SO.  with a title explaining that it was a test question being used to develop a bug report, and that I would delete it soon.  Never the less, it quickly received a bunch of down votes, and was eventually closed.  One user snidely suggested there was no bug.  This was particularly annoying because [the bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130736/bug-in-your-post-appears-to-contain-code-that-is-not-properly-formatted-as-code#comment359344_130736), when encountered, causes the question to be rejected, and so, by definition, the bug is not present in the versions (edits) of the question I successfully submitted.

Comment: Not relevant to your specific case per Jarrod's comment, but related to your general question: [Are bugtest questions okay?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63887/are-bugtest-questions-okay)

Comment: @PopularDemand: thanks for the reference.  I'll link this question in comments over there, as an example where the sandbox approach doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

I've unprotected the [Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox), so you can post answers now.

As you've seen from your Stack Overflow question, it's never proper to create debugging questions/answers there - just confine your research here.

Comment: Thanks!  However, it turns that MSO does *not* use the same heuristic as SO: the MSO sandbox [accepts the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130744/184610) that SO [rejects](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130736/bug-in-your-post-appears-to-contain-code-that-is-not-properly-formatted-as-code).  I will update the question to reflect this.

Comment: Yes, Meta doesn't have that "code format check" site setting enabled.  I don't think turning it on here is beneficial and we don't currently have a way to apply a site setting to a single post. However, your sandbox post details exactly what SO is rejecting, so we can evaluate it.

Comment: I reported the bug as a [separate MSO question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130736/bug-in-your-post-appears-to-contain-code-that-is-not-properly-formatted-as-code) before I had sandbox privileges. It would probably be better to evaluate the issue there.

Comment: Hey look, an inbox notification! (: