# Bug: Circular post-closing

Tags: bug, status-completed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prevent circular close as exact duplicate loop](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54024/prevent-circular-close-as-exact-duplicate-loop)

Turns out it's possible to close three posts as exact duplicate in a circular fashion. For example, Question 1 is closed as a duplicate of Question 2, which is closed as a duplicate of Question 1 (and presumably even the simpler case where Question 2 is a duplicate of Question 1).

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54024/prevent-circular-close-as-exact-duplicate-loop http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61566/you-can-vote-to-close-two-questions-as-duplicates-of-each-other EDIT: Nice, @Jon.