# Animations on up voting

Tags: discussion, april-fools

What's up with these animations whenever I up-vote/down-vote an answer? Is it a special day? <s>(Birthday, maybe?)</s>

EDIT: Oh no, it's March 31st where I am, but this may not hold true for SO-time...

[image: I am NOT a fool]

Comment: Just for the record, I think this is a *great* way to encourage voting on posts. We ought to keep it permanently.

Comment: @Cody The horror...

Comment: Not too new: http://stackoverflow.com/badges/804/suffrage

Comment: @muntoo ...you haven't used all your votes in one day?

Comment: w00t, when I just voted, I saw an unicorn running from right side on, targeting the horn on the vote number, stabbing it and running off screen on the left side, with the vote number on its horn! Oh boy, that was awesome!

Comment: Why is there an infinite recursive loop of duplicates!

Comment: So this post is closed as an exact duplicate of a post that is an exact duplicate of this post? Circular dependencies are bad.

Comment: @Cody - I agree. The animations should stay. Even if the unicorns go, we should replace them with something else.

Comment: Do we really need 24 hours of unicorn animations? UGH! It was funny the first few times, now it just is annoying. And *NO* please no permanent animations unless you can make it a user preference that I can turn off.

Comment: Very much doubtful that they'll stick around any longer. April Fools schenanigins rarely do.

Comment: @MartinDoms: We have a meta topic about that already: [Prevent circular close as exact duplicate loop](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/54024/15880)

Comment: I don't see any animation!

Comment: FYI unicorns are extinct. I thought that SEs are supposed to be constructive. I ewonder how many upvotes are wasted now just to see the pretty unicorns.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

UNICORNS! THEY ARE EVERYWHERE!

and... what is more **META** than unicorns dancing on unicorns dancing?

[image]

I'll tell you: **NOTHING**!

Comment: I hope you don't mind, but I added more meta.

Comment: There's a bug! Only the outer-most unicorn animates on this post.

Comment: Now I'm a little sad: what happens to the unicorns after Apr 1? Is there a correlation between the availability of pastel colored glue and Apr 2?

Comment: Whats with the unicorns?

Answer (score 69):

Neat.

[image: Yes]

Celebrating neatness!

[image]

Comment: Is that unicorn flipping us off?  Why would a unicorn give me the bird just for voting up?

Comment: With their one horn, unicorns are *always* flipping us off, expressing their disdain for our primitive human culture.

Comment: omg! There are 3 of them dancing for your upvote! XD

Comment: I've added the celebrations on neatness! if you don't mind. (0;

Answer (score 35):

It's the final feature that will turn SE into a multi-billion-dollar company! You know you love them...

And no, the fact it's April 1st has nothing to do with it.

Comment: sorry. I voted you down just to see the animation.  :-D

Comment: @Spudley - I'd do the same if I were allowed

Answer (score 29):

I found real.

[image]

Comment: That's a tricorn!

Answer (score 25):

Super Neat! This ones the BEST!!

[image]

**Note:** I undid/redid my vote a couple of times until they came again, dancing for me!

Answer (score 19):

I just love the downvote unicorns. They are very fast.

[image]

Herez another one: back-kicking version:

[image]

PS: I revoked the downvote on the questions :P

***There are many more...go n discover now...happy downvoting :)***

Comment: I missed these.  Is there a link to temporarily reactivate the April 1st behavior?

Answer (score 17):

[I have no idea.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81173/careers-2-0-featured-listing-web-company-needs-successor-for-retiring-unicorns)

Should add one handing out [unicorn dollars](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/a-new-name-for-stack-overflow-with-surprise-ending/).

Answer (score 4):

the animations are a real cute April 1st! I first stumbled over reading "Ponies and Balloons"
 in SO question and only later found the animations... upon first reading the words "Ponies and Balloons" and not being native English speaking I thought it's a figure of speech and found rather shocking evidence it's actually being a code phrase...

As much I love the animation this code phrase has a very negative association :-(

> One of her more shocking revelations
>   is that the BP cleanup team routinely
>   stage fake cleanup operations when
>   politicians come to inspect, and that
>   when the politician leaves, 85% of the
>   workers and resources rolled out for
>   his/her benefit are then pulled back.
>   The BP officials jokingly refer to
>   this hoax with the code phrase "Ponies
>   and Balloons".

Answer (score 3):

Could you add a setting to allow us to keep unicorns even after April 1st (maybe with a less-than-100% chance to occur)?

Comment: I would suggest that they appear if there are more than X votes.. ;)

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: that might cause some to hold off voting on a post until it has already reached the threshold - sort of a chicken and the egg.