# April 1st 2011 for the Kangaroo-Cowboys

Tags: support, april-fools

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Animations on up voting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85549/animations-on-up-voting)

Being that April 1st begins at 11am (UTC +11) for me, I'll be up for the very early stages of April 1st...can something happen now?

Comment: I had actually, but it would have been on the 31st of march I think...love it!

Comment: @Bill the Lizard, can you post your comment as an answer?

Comment: I guess the next step is a feature request for this to exist always...it's freaking awesome!

Comment: Feel free to test your up and down votes on this question created through my slackness

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You haven't upvoted any questions or answers yet, have you?

Comment: This will probably get flagged as "not an answer" now.  :)

Comment: well it is the correct answer...

Comment: No, it's a question :)

Comment: You're going to get a gold badge just from people testing.

Comment: @mmyers: Surely some people will be curious to see the down vote animation.  :)

Comment: @Bill: It was awesome. Post another answer so I can do it again. :)

Comment: @Bill: It turns out that if I down vote and cancel the down vote before it locks in, I still get the awesome animation (and the critic badge).

Comment: Not really... downvote triggers it too >:)

Comment: @Bill, if ever something happened in the right place .. at the right time, it was this answer.

Answer (score 6):

The answer to this question is [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/85549/152657).

The answer to that question [the latter] is [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/85554/152657).

Comment: not quite, ignoring that that question was closed (and that mine will be soon), I knew exactly what day it was...that question was asking what day it was...