# How to deals with april fool's unicorn vote animation related question?

Tags: discussion, flags, unicorns

[Like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5514454/did-you-know-that-dancing-unicorns-appear-if-you-upvote-a-question-today)
I expect many of them today.

Flag?
but how? off topic? belong to meta? then [duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85549/animations-on-up-voting)?

vote down?

Or just ignore?

Comment: Downvote, as the downvote animations are the best.

Comment: It's not cool! This is a legitimate question! please upvote at least one time every 5 down-vote! (At least Daniel will get a reversal badge...)

Comment: you can constantly downvote and upvote to see all animations :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Flag as duplicates, because they are.

Comment: +1 and the unicorns (three of them) rejoice for your opinion. Just flagged another as a dupe.

Comment: @giddy I think it was a terrible oversight that comment upvotes didn't get ponycorns (or is it ponicorns?)

Comment: but for others Stackexchanges sites?

Comment: @DavRob60 just because it's April Fool's Day doesn't mean duplicates cease to be duplicates - if a question is a duplicate, flag it as such, regardless of where it is.

Comment: @Daniel DiPaolo But I could flag as duplicate even if it'S on another Stackexchange site?

Comment: @DavRob60 - if it's the first time on that particular site it's been posted then I'd say no it's not a duplicate, you could probably post an answer to that question that is a link to the one here though

Comment: @Daniel ! Totally And I just found out only the trilogy get the sweet magic of unicorns! =O http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/915/why-arent-there-any-unicorns

Answer (score 1):

I saw a press release this morning that [Qualcomm have developed a technique](http://www.facebook.com/video/video.php?v=1409490558844) that truly does allow [real programmers to use butterflies](http://xkcd.com/378/). We could use this technology to [move offending users away from their keyboards](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lOVF0MOoBG4) for an appropriate amount of time if necessary or just [pin them down](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=60TrqCZW-vU&NR=1) for a bit, thereby stemming the flow of duplicates.