# How to encourage more voting? We have the answer

Tags: discussion, voting, april-fools

Well, [after today](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/85549), it seems perfectly clear how the team could incent more people to vote on posts.

A constant supply of entertaining animation looks like just the thing. I've spent the day looking for vote-worthy posts just to see the complete set.

Comment: I'd however love to see some voting stats of today as compared to past and future.

Comment: An amusing suggestion probably made lightheartedly, but note that you can see all the animations on a single question without any net effect by repeatedly voting and removing the vote.

Comment: +100 I seriously think this should be a permanent feature.

Comment: Funny. I went looking for CW posts so I could see the whole set.

Comment: +1 Didn't read the question, but wanted to see the unicorn

Comment: Is the answer "*putting a big dumb ring around the voting buttons"*?

Answer (score 28):

[image: yay for voting]

Comment: +1 for freehand circles (and the promise of an ambulating uniprong pony) yay!

Comment: We've got more accept votes than downvotes?  That's something I wouldn't have expected!

Comment: Also notice the corresponding uptick in downvotes at the bottom.  The lack of a boost in accept votes seems to indicate that site activity wasn't affected, but it might still be useful to see these normalized to account for overall site traffic.

Comment: It is questionable whether this would have a positive long-term effect. Remember the Windows XP Search Dog? Cute for the first day, annoying ever after.

Comment: @Piskvor the odds that we would introduce an animation every time people vote on a permanent basis are pretty much 0% take or give 0% percent.

Comment: @waffles♦: I'm pretty sure of that. I'm just doing my best to get my Humorless Pedant badge. (there *is* a Humorless Pedant badge, right? Right?)

Comment: @waffles: certainly not *always*. Basic reinforcement psychology: provide them unpredictably.