# Did the unicorns increased the voting ratio?

Tags: discussion

Is there any data available if the unicorns shown on 1st April increase the voting ratio (veg. voting/user)?

If yes we should use them permanently ;)

Comment: Well in my case they did! http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85549/animations-on-up-voting/85559#85559

Comment: In my case too, that's why I'm asking if this is a general pattern.

Comment: That's why I up-voted the question.

Comment: Based on a statistically valid sample of just myself, I am certain they increased the number of rapidly reversed votes to see what all the different animations were.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to encourage more voting? We have the answer.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85704/how-to-encourage-more-voting-we-have-the-answer)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that they did increase voting overall.  See [waffle's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85704/how-to-encourage-more-voting-we-have-the-answer/85721#85721) to "How to encourage more voting? We have the answer."