# Animation to encourage voting

Tags: feature-request, voting, unicorns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to encourage more voting? We have the answer.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85704/how-to-encourage-more-voting-we-have-the-answer)

Unicorns actually made people vote more on questions, and I think (although I have no reference handy) that total voting is on the decline.

How about some sort of animation when you vote?  It can be as simple as the up arrow bouncing up and down for a couple of seconds, just some simple visual feedback to encourage votes.

It doesn't have to be annoying or weird, just something more than it going yellow.  I think people will click on it more.

Comment: I _do_ miss the thumbs-up unicorn.

Comment: As much as I liked the unicorn's, I think that if it became a permanent fixture then all benefit would be lost within a few weeks as people got used to it.

Comment: Possible dupe http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85704/how-to-encourage-more-voting-we-have-the-answer