# Bookmark question/Notify when an answer has been posted/accepted

Tags: support, notifications

I come across questions that I find interesting and would like to find out later what the answer was. My attention span is not very long, so if someone will answer it, say within a minute, I may learn the answer, otherwise, the question is lost in the long stream of questions.

Is there a way to note these questions, get an email digest or smth else, where I can find what others said. I mean, I could do this with bookmarks, or with "Taboo" (FF plugin), but visiting a question later doesn't guarantee an answer has been posted.

Comment: We sure get a lot of questions from people who apparently have never noticed the "favorite" feature or wondered what that star is doing under the vote arrows. Maybe we need to bring back [those unicorns](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85549/animations-on-up-voting), this time on the stars.

Comment: :) I thought, the favorite feature was for labeling a really good question, a sort of "kudos" to the author. Now I know it isn't. Maybe, the terminology could match the word "bookmark" because one would be more familiar with firefox's star for bookmarks (aka favorites).

Comment: Yeah, I saw it suggested by someone the other day that "favorite" be changed to "bookmark". IE uses them as synonyms, but it looks like this feature is not discoverable to a lot of people. That seems to merit it some attention by devs, at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mark it as a Favourite by clicking the star under the vote buttons. I believe you will get a notification when questions are updated.

Comment: Hmmm, just tried it and I wasn't notified, but it did show in my favorites list, so  I guess I can check there for the answer. Thanks.