# Highest privilege

Tags: discussion

What is the highest privilege one can obtain in SO? does this lead to an official duty? I am asking this because I've seen members with huge reputations on their belt, a bit curious to know what privilege is up for grab for these members.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/privileges

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All privileges are described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges).

The current highest tier unlocks at 20,000 reputation:

> Trusted users are allowed to perform trusted actions, including:
>
> - Voting to delete answers with score of -1 or lower
> - Voting to delete questions immediately after they are closed (even if they are new)
> - Editing all tag wikis on the site

Some users are moderators and have a diamond after their name. Those users are either employees of Stack Exchange, temporarily appointed on new Stack Exchange sites, or elected by their communities. It's not necessary to have high reputation to become a moderator, but it often helps in elections since higher reputation tends to mean more active participation on the site. Community moderators have a number of abilities. You can read about them [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3783/what-abilities-are-moderators-given) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75189/what-are-diamond-moderators).

There are no other privileges that come with really high reputation.

Comment: Everything Anna said is right, but it's worth noting that 20k wasn't always the highest tier, and it might not remain the highest tier forever. There were no new privileges past 10k until a few months ago, and there's an -- admittedly facetious -- [open suggestion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101772/need-new-30k-abilities) to add privileges at 30k and higher.