# Should people with accepted answers be allowed to suggest tag synonyms?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tag-synonyms

The current requirement for proposing a tag synonym is five score in that tag. Would it make sense to also allow people with accepted answers to make proposals, even if they don't clear the score hurdle?

Comment: Also, the ability to vote on tag synonyms along with it.

Comment: Somewhat related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101772/need-new-30k-abilities/101778#101778

Answer (score 4):

An answer is accepted from a user because it helped him more than the other answers. Between an answer with a score of 5, and another answer with the same score that has been accepted, there isn't much difference in term of quality; it just means who asked the question preferred the other question for any reason: Maybe one question contained example code, while the other didn't use any example snippets; maybe the accepted question was given from a user the OP trusts better; maybe the accepted answer was more understandable from the OP because it used words that were more comprensible for the OP.

So far, I have seen accepted answers with a score of -2 or lower. In this case, the OP (a single user) accepted the answer, but 2 or more users down-voted it. I think the two down-votes count more than the answer being accepted.

Comment: They could just count an accepted answer as 5 votes for the purpose of synonym qualification, so if there were downvotes, then it would calculate that in.

Comment: To me, accepting an answer doesn't count as 5 votes, for the simple fact 5 votes require 5 different users, while accepting an answer requires just a user. I find that accepting an answer is rather subjective. It is true, also voting an answer could be subjective, but in that case 5 votes would be the subjective action of 5 different users, which still counts more than the action of a single user.

Comment: It could be the same user who upvoted 5 answers of yours ... which degrades to a single user.

Comment: @FooBah It could be, but it is not always so, which means that _could be_ doesn't mean _it is_.

Comment: FYI, I fixed the incorrect terminology in the question.