# Why are deleted comments not in Data Explorer

Tags: discussion, comments, data-explorer

I understand everything said in [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182091/could-30k-users-be-allowed-to-see-deleted-comments-please) about why comments should be brief and temporary. I'm far from that reputation count so that does not concern me at all.

The thing is I'd love to see all my comments and other users comments even if they were deleted. I know they are stored in a database and mods have access to them when they need some context.

Why can't we access deleted comments in Data Explorer ? What harm could it do to be able to see them ? Don't get me wrong, I'm sure there is a valid reason behind this. I just want to understand why they're not public.

Comment: If they were deleted for cause, what is the benefit of keeping them on display _somewhere else_ on the site? I can't think of many deleted comments that need to see the light of day again.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins Well they are being stored somewhere already. I'd consult them for the same reasons I would consult non-deleted comments in data explorer. Sometimes mod simply delete the comments because there are too many of them and the discussion is off topic. And it's okay like this. **But** It would be nice to go back and find them with a query. If I'm willing to take the time to go back and query the databse to find them, what harm can it do ?

Comment: Some of these deleted comments are *nasty*. Are you really prepared to see them?

Comment: Many comments are deleted for reasons that absolutely require hiding them from the world, including from Data Explorer, to protect Stack Exchange from legal trouble: slander, copyright infringements (as unlikely as that may seem in a comment), links to illegal/offensive web sites... there is currently no mechanism to tell those apart from "deleted because there were too many comments" ones

Comment: For the same reason deleted questions and answers don't show up in SEDE: Deleted is deleted. What would be the point of deleting stuff, if they were available on another site (of the network)?

Comment: @Pekka웃, in *comments*? Isn't that fair use by default?

Comment: @Frédéric yeah, most likely. I can't think of a real-world use case for that either. Just saying, SE has good reasons to keep deleted comments deleted....

Comment: @Yannis, I actually agree with that (deletion policy being another story), but if I'm not mistaken that content is not actually deleted. Moderators and higher can still see deleted questions, answers and comments, right?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi That's true, deletions are "soft". 10K+ users can see deleted questions and answers, and moderators can see deleted comments. However there is a difference between higher rep users being able to see deleted content for moderation reasons and having deleted content publicly available. 10K+ users can also vote to undelete, and that's why they get to see deleted content: To fix any mistakes.

Comment: @Yannis, I see, I thought there could be a discrepancy here but your last sentence makes the intent obvious in retrospect, especially since undeleted posts will "show back" later in SEDE. Thanks :) Back on-topic, that does not apply to comments, though, unless there is a way to undelete them.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi There's no way to undelete comments, and up until very recently moderators couldn't even see them. Again, the only reason we see them now is moderation. Sometimes, _unfortunately_, we have good reasons to dig through a user's comment history.

Comment: @Pekka post your first comment as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many comments are deleted for reasons that absolutely require hiding them from the world, including from Data Explorer, to protect Stack Exchange from legal trouble: slander, links to illegal/offensive web sites... there is currently no mechanism to tell those apart from "deleted because there were too many comments" ones, so there's no way to do this that doesn't come with this huge downside.