# Allow users to see deleted comments on their own posts

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, comments, privileges, deleted-comments

I know that moderator access tool (10k) is required in order to view deleted posts. I am talking about showing deleted comments on users' own posts.

For example, [this post of mine](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/11897/277)  has [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11896/what-are-mahavakyas#comment29516_11897) comment which seems for another user (not for me) but I think there should be some comment by another user (which is deleted) and this is the comment for that as a reply. (This is only my guess, there may be no deleted comments as I can't judge).

So, how about letting me see the deleted comments on my own posts?

Hence I am requesting to allow users to show deleted comments on their own post. (Or introduce a new privileges near about 3k etc for being able to see deleted comments on own posts)

Comment: I don't think we need comments that are deleted to be visible. If you find comments that serve no goal in improving the post or are left behind in a comment clean-up simply flag them as obsolete.

Comment: Note: 10k users do not see deleted comments at present. Only diamond mods have that ability.

Comment: [Related request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182091/could-30k-users-be-allowed-to-see-deleted-comments-please), which asks for the ability to see *all* deleted comments. This here is different, with less impact, so I think this might be a good idea - "broken" comments chain is often very confusing, and when on your own post, it's sometimes important you'll know what was going on.

Comment: What if the comments are simply insults or spam. Surely you don't need to be reminded of those every time you visit your own post.

Comment: When I delete a comment myself I expected it to be gone, by removing the comment, I have confirmed the comment has done its task (informed,recognized ,clarification,etc.).  Comments are deleted for lots of reasons, furthermore, they can be deleted for any reason at any time.

Answer (score 3):

Viewing deleted posts is fine. Once a post is deleted, you can do basically nothing to it: you can't comment, vote, edit etc - you can only flag for moderator attention.

Viewing deleted *comments* is more of a problem, because of the way comments are often used. I often see discussions going on in comment chains, which isn't really what comments are intended for. On sites where I'm a mod, I delete these comments (rolling the fruits of the discussion into the post itself, it it's worth it); on sites where I'm not I flag them and usually see them deleted not long after.

In cases where this discussion is between the poster and someone else, allowing the poster to see deleted comments would mean that deleting the discussion would have zero effect - the poster would still be able to see every comment, and would be able to continue the discussion unhindered, which defeats the point of the deletion.