# Keeping the upvote animation after april 1st has passed

Tags: feature-request, unicoins

I have grown fond of the upvote animation as i am sure most of you did as well, was wondering if we could choose to keep it after april 1st has passed.

The unicorns and I have bonded, it would be heartless and cruel to separate us now :(

Comment: Seriously, though, I am on board with this. Seriously.

Comment: Rally the troops we need to lobby for this !

Comment: I'm sure we got people here who can and will write a userscript. For a small fee of unicoins of course. :D

Comment: I am also for keeping the rep to the max :P

Comment: I equally like the downvote animation.  Actually, maybe more than the upvote.

Comment: Well, poop, I can't see it!

Comment: Just as an info for everyone who wasn't around in the good ol' days: The upvote animations are actually [2011's April 1st feature](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85549/animations-on-up-voting). And I'm pretty sure we had the same request back then.

Comment: Well, poop, You have to buy it using unicoins.

Comment: @balpha If we get enough attention would the feature be considered ?

Comment: @KeesSonnema Well, poop, not enough unicoins! :P

Comment: Never mined, I mind moar unicoins!

Comment: http://stackapps.com/q/2318/8939 this already is a userscript

Comment: i hope, they'll keep the cyan `Comic Sans` as text style for the comments. 
Can't live without it

Comment: @lootsch They didn't keep it, but that doesn't mean you can't have it: https://github.com/TheGuywithTheHat/SE-collection/blob/master/customizations/Cyan_Comic_Sans.user.js! _Note: You need greasemonkey/tampermonkey installed. You can then just click on "Raw", and have fun with cyan Comic Sans MS!_