# Circular duplicates in the close review queue?

Tags: feature-request, review, duplicate-questions

I just got this error message:

[image: circular duplicate thing]

Fair enough; I wasn't really paying attention to the duplicate link at the top of the suggested duplicate, just at the contents.

However, this question is [in the close votes](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/688952) review queue with a vote to close as a possible duplicate of the question that got closed as a duplicate of this one.

Can we exclude these posts from the review queue (or if it's not easy, run a job to get rid of them)? As circular duplicates are [verboten](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54024/prevent-circular-close-as-exact-duplicate-loop) they'll just languish in the queue forever; generating confusion and more meta posts like this one (or [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151474/possible-duplicate-points-at-confirmed-duplicate-of-this-question)).

P.S. I clicked do not close; this isn't a question about what to do in this situation.

Comment: They'll languish, but not forever, because close votes eventually expire. The exception is for questions with <100 views, but I would imagine that being in the queue would eventually push them over 100 views.

Comment: That was another question I meant to ask at some point. Do review views count as views? I'd have guessed that they shouldn't? If they do then this matters even less :-).

Comment: Well, people will get this dialog, and they'll think "what the heck?" and visit the question to see what makes it so special, and boom, that's a view.

Comment: I didn't; you can tell what's happening from the fancy new taby things the queues have going on.

Comment: I've met this error before when I reviewed a Suggested Edit. :s