# "possible duplicate" points at confirmed duplicate of this question

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, review, duplicate-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Circular duplicates in the close review?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/150133/circular-duplicates-in-the-close-review)

In the "review close votes" list, this question:

[Examples of code that compiles but executes differently in C versus C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579828/examples-of-code-that-compiles-but-executes-differently-in-c-versus-c)

is marked as a possible duplicate of this question:

[Can code that is valid in both C and C++ produce different behavior when compiled in each language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12887700/can-code-that-is-valid-in-both-c-and-c-produce-different-behavior-when-compile)

Which has *already been closed* as a duplicate of the first question.

Suggestion: 
Once question A has been closed as a duplicate of question B, any "close as duplicate of Question A" votes (on question B) should disappear...

Comment: It's been closed as 'Not constructive', I don't see where it was closed as an exact duplicate.

Comment: @Bart - nope.. not an exact duplicate of that one. Though if I did vote-to-close(dup) it does give me a warning about duplicate-loops.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker - if you go to the page for Question B it lists: "Possible Duplicate:    Examples of code that compiles but executes differently in C versus C++" Perhaps you're right it wasn't closed for that purpose - but it's clearly been voted on as being a dup of Question A - such that when I tried voting to close(as dup) it caused a "we don't like duplicate loops here" warning.

Comment: @TarynEast Could you then clarify (perhaps in your question) how this is not a duplicate? In my view, even after reading it again, you ultimately make the exact same feature request.

Comment: @Bart - just re-read that one... sorry, you're right it does look the same.

Comment: Hmmm. can't vote-to-close(dup) on my own question...

Answer (score 1):

The questions are exact duplicates.

I've merged them, with the older question being merged into the newer question. The older question has a mere fraction of the views and the votes the newer question does.

I've kept the newer question closed (this time as `not constructive`, which was the close reason for the old question, instead of it being a duplicate) to reflect the state of the questions before they were migrated.

If the community wishes to re-open the question, that's up to them.