# Remove votes to close question X as a duplicate of Y if question Y is closed as a duplicate of X

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

I just happened across [this question (let's call it question A)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13702228/cant-locate-loadable-object-for-module-cryptopensslrandom-in-inc-inc-con), which has one close vote suggesting that it be closed as an exact duplicate of [this question (which I'll call B)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13696578/cant-locate-loadable-object-for-module-cryptopensslrsa-in-inc).

This suggestion is perfectly correct: these are exactly identical questions asked by the same user.  However, there's not much point in closing question A as a duplicate of B, since *question B has already been closed as a duplicate of A*.

Yet the close vote remains, doing nothing but wasting reviewers' time.

This is not the first time I've seen this happen, so I'd like to suggest that the Stack Exchange software should do something about it.  In particular, I'd like to suggest the following feature:

> When a question Y is closed as an exact duplicate of another question X, any votes or flags to close X as a duplicate of Y should be automatically discarded.

Actually, I'm kind of surprised that the SE software doesn't do that already.  If anyone else thinks that this constitutes an actual bug, feel free to retag it.

Comment: Related/minor dupish: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/150133/circular-duplicates-in-the-close-review-queue; basically it can't be closed as a duplicate but as you say it appears everywhere...

Comment: Shouldnt you only be allowed to vote a question a duplicate if it was a question already asked in the past? If I ask a question and somebody else asks the same question a year later, why should my question be closed as a duplicate?

Comment: @n00b: There's no rule saying that the newer question must always be the one that's closed, especially not if it happens to be better than the old one. See e.g. [What to do when your question has an old, stale, unanswered duplicate?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40389/what-to-do-when-your-question-has-an-old-stale-unanswered-duplicate) and [What should you do when your exact question has already been asked, but badly?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138198/what-should-you-do-when-your-exact-question-has-already-been-asked-but-badly)

Comment: I totally agree. [This recently resulted](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1559241/119477) in what I think was a bad NRQ closure on "A"

Comment: [status-completed](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326955/839601)?