# Back ref double duplicate

Tags: discussion

Is it possible to mark a question as a duplicate of another, and then the latter as a duplicate of the former? Could it be sometimes useful?

I could imagine two answers which are both useful for example.

Comment: [It was once possible in the past.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54024/prevent-circular-close-as-exact-duplicate-loop)