# Circular duplicate link allowed

Tags: bug, status-completed, duplicate-questions

Circular duplicate links didn't used to be allowed, but I just did it:

[How to access the system tray using the keyboard?](https://superuser.com/questions/105773/how-to-access-the-system-tray-using-the-keyboard#question?noredirect=1)

[How to access (or switch between) tray icons with shortcut in windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/75903/how-to-access-or-switch-between-tray-icons-with-shortcut-in-windows)

[image: question one]

[image: question two]

Comment: Did you undo it? The first one isn't closed

Comment: @FDinoff yes, I undid it since I didn't actually want the circular reference to stay. If you look in the revision history you should see it.

Comment: `// TODO: implement circular dependency checking` oops...

Comment: What's the @@ button do?

Comment: @JarrodDixon I swear I was stopped once from making a circular reference, but maybe I'm conflating that with it stopping me from marking as a duplicate of a deleted question. Either way, could you make it [meta-tag:status-planned] if that's appropriate?

Comment: @Undo wouldn't you like to know! :P

Comment: No, the code used to be there, but most of the flagging/closing code was refactored.  Part of the plan was to implement [Tarjan's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm) for finding circular dupes.

Comment: @nhinkle Really - superping?

Comment: @Undo it's a userscript that one of the SU mods wrote that copies the superping string for each user who voted to close a question. We use it to send reminders via chat to users who vote to migrate questions to SU that don't belong there.

Comment: @JarrodDixon with the automatic redirect for anonymous users on duplicates, what happens when there's a circular reference?

Comment: We get an exception in our logs.  And I am deprived of my dinner.

Comment: @JarrodDixon I'm glad to hear that they take these things seriously over there. What happens to the user? "Oops, something went wrong" or "infinite redirect loop"?

Comment: Probably an infinite redirect loop on the client.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54024/prevent-circular-close-as-exact-duplicate-loop

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Alright, I've added some protection against this via a [neat library](https://github.com/danielrbradley/CycleDetection) that [danielrbradley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/366550/danielrbradley) created.

There's sure to be some issues (which we'll log when a block occurs), but the base cases are covered (and unit tested, oh my!).

Comment: That was speedy! Thanks.

Comment: It was a regression that was totally my fault - I couldn't go home and leave it borked :)

Comment: Now the check is bit [too strict](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186981/152859). :/

Comment: FYI there is [another regression](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263331/circular-duplicates-strike-again).