# Questions closed as duplicates without second thoughts

Tags: discussion, duplicate-answers

ok, I found that funny: both questions are marked as duplicate of each other!

[Why are most marketing tags (Omniture, XE, etc) written with document.write()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581340/why-are-most-marketing-tags-omniture-xe-etc-written-with-document-write)

[Why use document.write?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556322/why-use-document-write)

Generally speaking, I find that people tagging duplicates should give it more thought. I recently had a question closed because a similar question with an accepted but inaccurate answer was posted... 4 years ago!

[svg on older IE browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19364911/svg-on-older-ie-browsers)

Not sure how this could work, but I just wish there was a safeguard to prevent people from jumping too fast on the close button, and maybe give the OP a chance to explain the difference. The points I wanted to make with my examples:

- it's strange to mark a question as duplicate of a more recent question
- people should understand that 4 years are a lot in the programming world and that the older answer is possibly outdated
- accepted answer doesn't necessarily mean correct answer

Comment: What is the discussion you're looking for here?

Comment: @Bart Well, at the very least, one of the two should be reopened.

Comment: @Servy Fair enough, but is that the main point here? I see circular dupe, somewhat of a rant, and a complaint about a closed question from the OP. Some focus would be nice.

Comment: Are you saying it's a bug? Or that it shouldn't happen? Or that people should spend some time reviewing what they're closing?

Comment: @Bart I edited my post. To be honest, I was in ranting mode as I've had this on my chest for some time. I hope this is now more useful.

Comment: "4 years are a lot in the programming world..." The same browsers are mentioned in both SVG/IE questions.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I get your point, and this is similar to Servy's comment below. The fact is that in 4 years people have found new ways to address the question (I mention some in my own post), but the old post has never been updated.

Answer (score 6):

It's an odd edge case.  Both questions were being closed at right around the same time, they each had some votes to close as a duplicate of the other before either was actually closed.

If memory serves, there has since been a code change to prevent this from happening in the future.

In any case, you can simply flag one of the post stating that there's a circular duplicate closure and a mod will handle it.

To your edited points:

1. There is *nothing* wrong with marking a question as a duplicate of a newer question.  Whatever question is better or has more valuable content should be the canonical question that is left open, regardless of when it's asked.
2. If the answers to a question are outdated then either post updated answers to the canonical question, or ensure that the new question differentiates itself from the existing question; make it clear that the answer(s) to that question do not work, and explain why.  Then the questions are no longer duplicates.
3. Again, if there isn't a good answer on the duplicate question than one can always be added.  If you really need to you can always add a bounty to the question to look for better answers.

Comment: I would not be surprised if someone initially voted to close the old one as a dupe of the newer question, with others then thinking it should be the other way around. But yeah, shouldn't happen any more as far as I'm aware.

Comment: FWIW, circular dupe closure happened less than 2 weeks ago (Oct 16) to this pair at MSO: [1](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200122/why-are-the-best-questions-the-ones-which-have-been-closed) and [2](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167516/how-can-i-encourage-stack-overflow-to-rein-in-the-subjective-vigilantes). I flagged one of these and moderator fixed that

Comment: @gnat Hmm, [shouldn't really have happened I think](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186745/circular-duplicate-link-allowed). Bug perhaps then?

Comment: [Race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) I guess, concurrent actions along with caching are a slippery mix. Look, at question #1 user from Texas clicks the last VtC and, wow, question is closed immediately. At #2, at about the same time, a user from India clicks the last VtC and, wow, question is closed immediately. `2x wow = WTF`, to avoid that SE would have to check whether vote is final (5th or mod's binding) and lock/sync globally before applying it - that would introduce slowdown

Comment: +1 thanks for the specific answers. I agree with most of this, the one point that worries me is trying to recycle an old post (we're talking about 3-4 years ago) that has a forest of outdated answers. Especially in my second example as people following the link will naturally be drawn to the accepted answer.

Comment: An older question with lots of views, votes, and that is the target of a lot of links will have much more google juice, so if you don't answer there, but rather in another question with lower visibility than everyone other than the OP looking for the question will only find the old lower quality answers and never the newer ones.  If they're on the canonical question then they're much more discoverable.  If it's a much better answer then over time it's reasonably likely to see a close in the vote difference.