# Two questions are duplicates of each others?

Tags: support, flags, duplicate-questions

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8700870/3204827) question is marked as a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11178673/3204827) question, but the second question is also marked as a duplicate of the first question. The same mod closed both questions. I flagged the question 12 days ago, but it hasn't been reopened

[This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/186754/254778) answer says:

> Alright, I've added some protection against this via a neat library that danielrbradley created.
>   There's sure to be some issues (which we'll log when a block occurs), but the base cases are covered (and unit tested, oh my!).

But it doesn't seem to have caught this one.

Comment: Out of curiosity - why did you tag this as a software bug?

Comment: The information in the bug tag says: "This tag indicates a reproducible problem on the site that you believe is due to a mistake, malfunction, or programming error." And according to the answer Jarrod Dixon gave on the other Meta question, this shouldn't happen. So it would be a mistake/programming error?

Comment: I've voted to re-open the one with more votes. It could be that it is a duplicate of another post still. The closures are far enough apart that Casper probably didn't notice the circular dupe link.

Comment: Can you link to this other Meta question, please?

Comment: @Howlin: Moderators have more powers than regular users, including the ability to override guards. That was Caspar's downfall here.

Comment: @Oded: I think he's referring to this one: [Circular duplicate link allowed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/186754)

Comment: @MartijnPieters - yeah, figured it might me something like that. Not sure that even mods (or devs, for that matter) should be able to override that, but could be by design.