# Dupehammer enabling circular duplicates?

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions, dupehammer

The Stack Overflow question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23750620/update-values-based-on-case-statement has been closed as a duplicate of [How to update values using case statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23750852/how-to-update-values-using-case-statement), which has itself been closed as a duplicate of the first.

This is [normally prevented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186745/circular-duplicate-link-allowed), and the only difference to normal seems to be the dupehammer used in one of them.

Comment: FYI: When I closed [this (Q1)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23750620/update-values-based-on-case-statement) as a duplicate it had four close votes but none as duplicate. [The other question (Q2)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23750852/how-to-update-values-using-case-statement) also had four close votes and probably all was close as duplicate. I chose as I did because the second Q had an answer. About 2 hours after Q1 was closed there was a fifth close as duplicate vote on Q2.