# How can a question be tagged with a tag synonym?

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms

The question [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54024/prevent-circular-close-as-exact-duplicate-loop) seems to be tagged with [close](/questions/tagged/close), which, last I checked, is a synonym of [vote-to-close](/questions/tagged/vote-to-close). How is it possible that a question can be tagged with a synonym? Don't synonyms automatically get replaced on questions?

Comment: The question was most probably tagged with [meta-tag:close] **before** it became a synonym.

Comment: @Oded I once filed a synonym request, and the offending question was automatically retagged.

Comment: Was the question _edited_ **after** the synonym was created? Or possibly simply retagged?

Comment: @Oded Look at the [revisions](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16976142/revisions) for [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16976142/). When I added in the tag [tag:java-web-start], I actually added two tags, that and [tag:webstart]. However, the tags were merged, and there is no trace of the old tag. Why is there a discrepancy here as to what happens in such a case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creating a synonym does not ever cause an automatic merging of the questions. All it does is remap future occurrences of the tag to the master tag.

When I created that synonym relationship, I didn't bother merging them for whatever reason. That means any questions that were already tagged with [close](/questions/tagged/close) kept that tag. If the post gets further edited, or a tag merge takes place, the tag will be automatically remapled at that point. Until then, it keeps the original tag.

Tag merges are not automated because it helps fix mistakes. If we just create a synonym that shouldn't have been created, we can easily delete the synonym and all the questions which previously had the tag will have it once again. Once a merge is done, that process is incredibly tedious, as it has to be done manually.

Comment: What about in my case?

Comment: What about it? That question was asked long ago, and the synonym was only recently created. Unless you're referring to something else?

Comment: I'm referring to the question linked in the last comment on this question.

Comment: When a tag merge takes place, it doesn't create new revisions for all the questions that had the tag. It simply replaces all occurrences of the old tag with the new tag. In cases where the new tag already exists, it just removes the old tag.

Comment: So, did a merge take place in that situation? Or did the system remove the old tag automatically to prevent the question from being tagged with the same thing twice?

Comment: It depends on when you did the retag. If the synonym already existed, then the tag would have been remapped to the master tag and it would be removed as a duplicate tag.