# Duplicate questions both deleted within a minute of closing the newer one--mistake or deliberate?

Tags: support, specific-question, duplicate-questions

A new user reposted a question after a couple of hours. He responded to the "possible duplicate of..." comment left by the first close vote with a comment saying `sir i haven't got any answers for this question...could you please help me to find out`. I cast the fifth close vote and tried to post a response telling him how to edit the original question rather than reposting, but I couldn't post the comment because apparently the question had already been deleted, within a minute of being closed. I followed the link to the original question in order to post the comment there, but that one was gone too. I know it was definitely still there a couple of minutes earlier because I visited it while doing the review. I thought maybe for some reason the user had been deleted, causing both questions to disappear simultaneously, but [the account is still there](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3236974/user3236974).

As far as I could tell it was a legitimate question, on-topic and complete with code, an image demonstrating the problem, and a clear explanation. Did each get deleted as a duplicate of the other by mistake (in which case one of them should be restored), or was there some reason they were both whacked?

(The embedded image didn't have any freehand red circles, but if I'm not mistaken that's only considered grounds for deletion on meta.)

- [Original version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21398390/while-saving-image-after-updating-in-grid-view-not-saving-in-proper-format)
- [Reposted version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21400170/not-properly-updating-image-from-datagridview-in-winform-application)

I realize [there's a feature to identify questions mutually closed as duplicates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54024/prevent-circular-close-as-exact-duplicate-loop), but that doesn't apply here because only one was *closed*, and they were both deleted.

Comment: Both were closed. The original post was closed a dupe of [after updating image from data grid view getting black color instead of images](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21361610), the repost was closed as a dupe of the first one.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Granted, the one was closed by just a mod right before it was deleted.

Comment: Both posts were deleted by the same moderator. This wasn't an accident.

Answer (score 6):

The original question was closed as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21361610/after-updating-image-from-data-grid-view-getting-black-color-instead-of-images, by a moderator.

The same moderator then deleted both questions, most likely because the OP was using sock-puppet accounts to re-post the question. In other words, you ran into a user too impatient to wait for answers, and a moderator dealt with it by cleaning up.

Note that the [account that posted the questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3236974/user3236974) has been put in the [penalty box](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) as well.

Comment: Yup. All their questions were exact duplicates of ones posted by their previously suspended account. There was no point in keeping them around, so I cleaned them up when I suspended this third account of this user.

Answer (score 4):

Both questions were duplicates of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21361610/after-updating-image-from-data-grid-view-getting-black-color-instead-of-images).  The user even created an entirely new account just to copy/paste the same question out there *again*, trying to get more attention.

The practice of having people continually repost the exact same question over and over again when they don't get the desired attention is quite problematic; the new questions were adding no new value, so they were simply deleted, leaving only the original question.