# Not possible to type an @-sign into input

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WMD editor bug: German keyboard layout - “@” creates blockquote section](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13065/wmd-editor-bug-german-keyboard-layout-creates-blockquote-section)

Whenever I try using an @-sign (this one is actually copy-pasted) in the question or answer inputbox, it actually creates an blockquote like this:

> Blockquote

This happens because I use an German keyboard where you type <kbd>AltGr+Q</kbd> for the @-sign and the shortcut for a blockquote is <kbd>Ctrl+Q</kbd>.