# Why is the editor shortcut problem not solved yet?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WMD editor bug: German keyboard layout - “@” creates blockquote section](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13065/wmd-editor-bug-german-keyboard-layout-creates-blockquote-section)

Why [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2051/why-is-alt-gr-q-giving-me-quote-formatting-instead-of-the-sign-closed) is not solved? It was asked a year ago!

Comment: Good Question...

Comment: One has to love that those questions were closed as mutual duplicates.

Comment: @Georg: I certainly do. NOT.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because the team decided it wasn't important enough, or they weren't like fixing it.

Comment: More likely is that because of *another bug* (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54024/) the two questions that mention the problem have both been closed as duplicates of each other and both vanished from the radar.