# Alt Gr + Y won't insert ">" character in question/answer using Hungarian keyboard

Tags: bug, status-completed, editor

I use a Hungarian keyboard:

[image: Hungarian keyboard]

If I press <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd>, which should insert a <kbd>></kbd> character, nothing happens. I have to press <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> (dot) to achieve this.

This is really annoying when answering/writing questions, and this happens on every website related to Stack Exchange, including Stack Overflow, but nowhere else.

Comment: Does this happen to other (not SE related) sites too?

Comment: @GamecatisToonKrijthe No.

Comment: This is caused by raw conversion from keyCode to character. The correct way is to use key, but key is not yet implemented in some browser (at least Firefox). I loled when I look at this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/KeyboardEvent (which, keyCode, key, charCode, char)

Comment: @nhahtdh `keyCode` is deprecated, ***since when***?!

Comment: @DJDavid98: At least that's what MDN says. But even if it is not deprecated, the keyCode is system and implementation dependent, so I think it is most likely the reason.

Comment: I noticed you tagged Chrome, does the problem persist in other browsers?

Comment: @Robotnik Yes it does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was essentially the same bug as [WMD editor bug: German keyboard layout - "@" creates blockquote section](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13065/wmd-editor-bug-german-keyboard-layout-creates-blockquote-section). The browser reports <kbd>Alt-Gr</kbd> as being the key combination <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, and the editor didn't quite handle that. The fix from the other bug didn't fix this particular case, since handling the undo/redo controls (including <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>, which was the culprit here) happens in a different place than the rest of the keyboard shortcuts (like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> in the other issue).

This is [fixed](https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/source/detail?r=7bf1d3cd5ed557523db65bf5615d53e465816a96) in the next build of the site (until then, you can confirm this by testing it [on the PageDown demo page](http://pagedown.googlecode.com/hg/demo/browser/demo.html)).

There are still some issues with the editor and <kbd>Alt-Gr</kbd> that I should fix at some point, but they should be minor.